# jinja2: TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'string'

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I am new to Jinja2 and having an issue with using python regular expression (re). In the following code I would like to bold the lines that have error string in them.

```
  {% block content %}
    <div class="container">
      {% for l in lines %}
         {% if re.search(r"Error", l) %}  {# <<< Throws error #}
            <b> {{ l }} </b>
         {% else %}
            {{ l }} <hr>
         {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

The re.search above throws following error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError
TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'string'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Raw python code is not fully supported in jinja2 template syntax.

```
{% if re.search(r"Error", l) %}
```

replace this line with

```
{% if "Error" in l %}
```

can fix your problem.

if your logical condition is more complicated, you should consider defining your own [custom filters](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#custom-filters)(which can call any python code) or do the complicated things in your view layer. also go check [global namespace](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#global-namespace).